# SLOC in cppcheck

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I want to write checker that can be added to other checkers in CppCheck. This checker must check SLOC of all member function, for example the function should contain no more than 200 significant lines of code. But in CppCheck I only found method that checks the existence of a body `hasBody()`, but not a count of lines.

Comment: And you question is?

Comment: @user1034749 how i can count the number of lines in function code.

Answer (score 0):

I am a cppcheck developer. I am no expert in this topic. I think it depends on exactly what you want to count. how many lines is this:

```
void f() { int x=3; int y=x+2; dostuff(x+y+4); }
```

I would guess that you want to go through the tokens and count semicolons or something:

```
for (tok = functionScope->classStart; tok != functionScope->classEnd; tok = tok->next()) {
    if (tok->str() == ";")
        ++lines;
}
```

I think this checker you suggest is interesting but it does not fit well in the core cppcheck tool. I would suggest that you write an addon. I will be happy to add it in our addons folder and show it in the GUI etc.

By the way.. I have thought that it would be nice to integrate (execute and read results) ohcount, cccc, or whatever in the GUI so extended statistics can be shown.